# How to use live binding to bind blob field to TImage control?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, livebindings

I am using Delphi XE2 to write a VCL win32 application.  Delphi XE2 support live binding.  I load sample Biolife.xml into a TClientDataSet instance.

I able to bind a TEdit control to dataset's string field: Species Name:

```
object BindLinkEdit11: TBindLink
  Category = 'Links'
  SourceMemberName = 'Species Name'
  ControlComponent = Edit1
  SourceComponent = BindScopeDB1
  ParseExpressions = <>
  FormatExpressions = <
    item
      ControlExpression = 'Text'
      SourceExpression = 'DisplayText'
    end>
  ClearExpressions = <>
end
```

I then trying to bind Graphic field to TImage control:

```
object BindLinkImage11: TBindLink
  Category = 'Links'
  SourceMemberName = 'Graphic'
  ControlComponent = Image1
  SourceComponent = BindScopeDB1
  ParseExpressions = <>
  FormatExpressions = <
    item
      ControlExpression = 'Picture'
      SourceExpression = 'Value'
    end>
  ClearExpressions = <>
end
```

Apparently, it doesn't work.  Is that possible to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look into the `BindLinkVCLProject` demo project. There is shown also a binding for the image, so my guess is you need to do it this way (the `Self` in `SourceExpression` represents a blob field):

```
object BindLinkImageHandler: TBindLink
  Category = 'Links'
  SourceMemberName = 'Graphic'
  ControlComponent = Image1
  SourceComponent = BindScopeDB1
  ParseExpressions = <
    item
      ControlExpression = 'Picture'
      SourceExpression = 'Self'
    end>
  FormatExpressions = <
    item
      ControlExpression = 'Picture'
      SourceExpression = 'Self'
    end>
  ClearExpressions = <
    item
      ControlExpression = 'Picture'
      SourceExpression = 'nil'
    end>
end
```